# How to hide some API methods in Strapi documentation

Tags: strapi

I use `documentation` plugin for Strapi and I need to hide some entities in API. How I can do it?

Answer (score 0):

Please check here the documentation about the documentation plugin https://strapi.io/documentation/3.0.0-beta.x/guides/api-documentation.html#overriding-the-suggested-documentation

You will find how customize the generated documentation.

We have an issue about hiding routes - the override system is okay to change content of the documentation but not for deleting a route.
So I suggest you to update the `./extensions/documentation/documentation/[versioin]/full_documentation.json` file.
Find your route and delete it.

But be careful if you re-generate the doc, your update will be removed.

This is a workaround fr the issue we have.

Comment: Is this still not overrideable?

Comment: your link is not valid anymore. [this is the new](https://docs.strapi.io/developer-docs/latest/plugins/documentation.html#overriding-the-suggested-documentation)